# Can the Fractional Reserve System be used by the Common Man

Tags: banking

Say... I ask my neighbor for $10 and promise him $11.

I then turn around and invest my $100 [post multiplier] into a govt bond.

Then I give him his $1 and keep the rest.

Is that possible on a personal level or does one need to establish a bank?

Comment: `one need to establish a bank` Nobody will give you a banking license just like that. `I ask my neighbor for $10 and promise him $11` Will your neighbour lend you money just willy nilly ?

Comment: Welcome thistleknot - I am going to put this question on hold as it doesn't fall within out on-topic list:  http://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic  If you want to edit it after reading the help, it can be reopened.

Comment: I did think about this before answering, but it seems on-topic in that what the OP wants to do relates to personal finance, albeit that it's impossible/misguided. As far as the on-topic list in the FAQ goes, it could be considered under "Strategies for earning more money".

Comment: The basic question (minus the extraneous part) seems to be, "Can an individual borrow money and invest it?" In that form the question is valid for personal finance, but the answer seems blindingly obvious since people do this every day.

Comment: I think it's more "can I get the same 'multiplier' on my money that banks apparently get".

Answer (score 6):

The $10 you borrow won't just magically turn into $100.

What a bank does is to "borrow" $10 by taking a deposit of $10.

It promises that the depositor (your neighbour in this case) can have the money back whenever they want. It also lends out most of that $10 to someone else, e.g. as a mortgage. That money then finds its way back to the bank as another deposit from someone else, and the bank lends it out again, and so on.

The fractional reserve requirement is the amount that the bank doesn't lend out this way. So if it was 10%, then only $9 of the original deposit will be loaned out. When it comes back, only $8.10 will go out, and so on. That adds up to $100 - another way of looking at it is that the $10 is 10% of the eventual $100.

Now the bank is on the hook for $100 of deposits that can be demanded at will, but only has $10 to actually cover them. So it has to hope that everyone doesn't ask for them at once.

You could in theory do this for yourself, but in practice it's unlikely that anyone would believe your promise to return the deposits on demand, and there would likely also be legal restrictions.

Comment: +1 Also explained here: [Understanding the Fractional Reserve Banking System](http://www.learningmarkets.com/understanding-the-fractional-reserve-banking-system/)